# Does Google read and value text placed inside <detail> tag

Tags: google-search, html5

HTML5 has a `<detail>` tag (explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp)) that shows a summary and shows all text if clicked on read more. Does Google value content inside  tag as much as text written outside it?

Answer (score 2):

If the content is viewable only when a user has to click on button to view it, that Googlebot will use that content to determine what a page is about. But content that is visible on a page without requiring a user to take an action to view it is far more likely to be used by Googlebot to determine a page's topic.

Googlebot can render your pages to see how they are visible to their customers. As a result, content that is hidden from a user until they click a button to view it is considered part of the page's content, but not nearly as much as content that is automatically viewable.